# insert object if it not exist in neo4j db

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I've got an object that looks like this

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@NodeEntity
public class GPlayer {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Relationship(type = "comrade", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private Set<GPlayer> comrades;
    // @Indexed(unique = true) doesn't work in v4
    private String name;

    /**
     * Adds new comrade.
     *
     * @param comrade comrade
     */
    public void acquainted(GPlayer comrade) {
        if (null == comrades) {
            comrades = new HashSet<>();
        } else {
            if (comrades.contains(comrade)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        comrades.add(comrade);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;

        GPlayer gPlayer = (GPlayer) o;

        if (!id.equals(gPlayer.id)) return false;
        return name.equals(gPlayer.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + id.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GPlayer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", comrades=" + comrades +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I want to store it in `Neo4j` with unique `name`. So when I insert `GPlayer` - if the object with such name doesn't exist I don't want to insert it.

I have repository that looks like this

```
public interface GraphPlayerRepository extends GraphRepository<GPlayer> {
    List<GPlayer> findAll();
    GPlayer findByName(String name);
}
```

To insert I do like this

```
private Long createPlayer(String playerName, String comrade, GraphPlayerRepository gRepo) {
    GPlayer gPlayer = gRepo.findByName(playerName);
    if (null == gPlayer) {
        gPlayer = new GPlayer();
        gPlayer.setName(playerName);
        if (null != comrade) {
            gPlayer.acquainted(gRepo.findByName(comrade));
        }
        gRepo.save(gPlayer);
        LOGGER.info("Created new GRAPH player: {}", gPlayer);
    } else {
        gPlayer.acquainted(gRepo.findByName(comrade));
        gRepo.save(gPlayer);
        LOGGER.info("Updated player: {}", gPlayer);
    }
    return gPlayer.getId();
}
```

But it looks rather verbose. Is there a way to make it simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the name as the id of the entity

```
@Index(unique=true, primary=true)
private String name;
```

Then no need to declare the `findByName` method, just use `Neo4jRepository`

```
public interface GraphPlayerRepository extends Neo4jRepository<GPlayer, String> {
...
}
```

and use `repository.findOne(name)` to get players from the name.

That said, **the implementation of hashCode and Equals is incorrect** : it is strongly advised not to use the `Long id` in these. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.2.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference:annotating-entities:graph-id:equality).

Otherwise, not related to SDN, but improvements could include :

- use lombok to generate hashcode and equals
- initialize the hashSet at the field level

You could also migrate to SDN 5 and make use of Optional return types to avoid the if/else nullity check blocks.

Comment: Will `@Index` serve as a replacement for `GraphId`?

Comment: Not really, you still need the @GraphId with SDN 4. But the primary index will be used as a lookup key for the entity.

Comment: So I have to leave `Long id` with @graphId?

Comment: Yes (with SDN 4. From SDN 5 it is not needed anymore.